Which delta for hedging?
I want to dynamic delta hedge an option but I'm confused of what delta shoud I use to hedge it.
Let's suppose I buy at T(0) a long CALL at strike 100 with implVol(0) = 30% and Delta(0) = 62
Let's suppose I forecast at T(end) an implVol(end) = 70% and it's Delta(end)=55
Should I dinamically hedge day by day, calculating delta using implVol(0), implVol(t) or implVol(end) ?
Thank you

A common practice is to hedge day by day, using ImplVol(t) on Day t

You may even decide to save on transaction costs and only re-hedge once your risks drift outside your comfort zone, which may be less than every day.
